# Run-time error 1004 'Unable to get the TextJoin Property of the WorksheetFunction class.'

Tags: excel, vba

When ever I run my macro, I get the following error

> "Run-time error 1004. "Unable to get the TextJoin Property of the
> WorksheetFunction class."

This is my code

```
 Worksheets("PNListed").Range("A1") = WorksheetFunction.TextJoin(" ", True, _
        Worksheets("BurnDownPN").Range("A:A"))
```

So basically, I copy the values from column A and paste the values to a new sheet. The macro runs when there a few values in column A, but as soon as there's thousands, it gives me this error. That's the only things difference I noticed.

Comment: From [HERE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) `If the resulting string exceeds 32767 characters (cell limit), TEXTJOIN returns the #VALUE! error.`

Comment: Instead find the last cell with values then loop those and concatenate them.  But realize a cell can only hold 32767 characters also